# PostgreSql foreign table select fails due to special characters rows

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper, tds-fdw

I just set up a new foreign table and it works as intended if I just select the "ID" (integer) field.

When I add the "Description"(text) field and try to select the table, it fails with this error message:

```
utf-8 'Codec cannot decode byte 0xfc in position 10: invalid start byte
```

After checking the remote table, I found that "Description" contains special characters like: "ö, ü, ä"

What can i do to fix this?

---

Table definitions (Only first 2 rows)

Remote table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    [Id] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

Foreign table:

```
Create Foreign Table "Test" (
    "Id" Char(8),
    "Description" VarChar(50)
) Server "Remote" Options (
    schema_name 'dbo', table_name 'test'
);
```

---

Additional information:

- Foreign data wrapper: [tds_fdw](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw)
- Local server: Postgres 12, encoding: UTF8
- Remote server: Sql Server, encoding: Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: Please tell us a) which foreign data wrapper you are using (doesn't sound like postgres_fdw) b) what the server encodings on both databases are c) how the foreign server and the foreign table were defined.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the response, please check out the edit.

Comment: What it's telling you is the 10th character is an invalid UTF-8 character. Probably due to incorrectly converting from Latin-1 to UTF-8. 0xfc is `ü` in Latin-1. For simplicity, you could set that column to also be Latin-1. Or the whole table or schema as appropriate.

Comment: Did you try setting ´client charset = UTF-8` in `freetds.conf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe) suggested in the comments, I created a `freetds.conf` in my PostgreSQL folder with the following content:

```
[global]
tds version = auto
client charset = UTF-8
```

Don't forget to set the path to the configuration file in the environment variable `FREETDS`.

Powershell:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('FREETDS','C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12',[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```